# Exchange Server 2013 EMail Driver

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2013

I have a C# program that connects to my Exchange Server 2010 and is able to read every email.

I am using the `microsoft.exchange.webservices.dll` library.

The problem is, that this program gives back the following exception on Exchange Server 2013: 
`"The remote server returned an error: (501) Not Implemented."`

I have no idea what's the difference between these 2 servers.

Edit:
Some Code Snippets:

`ExchangeVersion version = ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013;
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(version);
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pw", "domain");
service.AutodiscoverUrl("emailaddr");`

and here happens the exception:

`SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));`

`FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, sf, new ItemView(20));`

`service.LoadPropertiesForItems(findResults.Items, PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);`

`string mailsender = item.LastModifiedName;`

Comment: Please show us the code you are using where the error is. It's possible that your code is only targeting Exchange Server 2010

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I was wondering also about the `Exchange Server` but decided to leave it and missed entirely the `c#`

Comment: @OurManInBananas: I felt that "Exchange Server 2013" was an adjective phrase qualifying "Email Driver". Q: "What kind of email driver?" A: "Exchange Server 2013 Email Driver".

Comment: @xileb0: do you have this code in your initialization of EWS: 
`ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);// ` ?

Comment: Probably a mismatch between server and EWS assembly version, is it the latest one from NuGet? Does it have an SP1 option in the ExchangeVersion enum?

Comment: Does it work if you just do a normal ItemView with no filter? Just wondering if what you are doing with your search filter is causing an issue (not that it looks like you are doing anything strange...)

Comment: Throws the same exception if i do this:
`FindItemsResults <Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(10));`

Comment: It looks like whatever I'd like to load from the mailbox, this exception occurs. Just tried to find a folder. Same thing...
But why?

Comment: @xileb0: when you type `ExchangeVersion` then the period (or full-stop in *GB English*) what are the available options?

Comment: A little update:
I tried this tool: https://ewseditor.codeplex.com/

It is able to show me all the information of the server, but when I try to open a message folder it shows the same exception.

Comment: I think i am close to the solution:

I am already able to display mails from the inbox. The problem is, whenever I use `item.Load()`, or `item.Delete(DeleteMode.HardDelete)`, the 501 expection still occurs. 

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Guys, I actually found the problem:
When I use the Fiddler Web Debugger to check the communication between Client and Exchange Server and activate "Decrypt HTTPS traffic" in the options, my program works without any problems. When I close Fiddler, the problem returns.

How would you handle that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the problem:

There was a load balancer between exchange server and my server. I'm bridging this load balancer now -> Works perfectly